# Change font for math functions (sin, log, etc.) in ConTeXt MkIV?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, context, context-mkiv

When I’m using the Euler font for math, I notice that since Euler is upright, the font for math functions like sin, cos, and log is identical to variables.  Is there a way to change the font for math function to be the same as in text mode?

Example:

```
\usetypescriptfile[euler]
\definetypeface[mainface][rm][serif][palatino]       [default]
\definetypeface[mainface][ss][sans] [helvetica]        [default] [rscale=auto]
\definetypeface[mainface][mm][math] [pagellaovereuler] [default] [rscale=auto]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,12pt]
\appendtoks \rm \to \everymathematics
\setupmathematics
  [lcgreek=normal, ucgreek=normal, integral=nolimits]

\starttext
\startformula
  f = \sin i\omega x
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Render result:

[image]

I would like it to be like

[image]

I used `\text{sin}\,` there, but obviously is not a rigorous solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in today's beta (`ver: 2015.05.09`). The labels for `\sin`, `\cos`, etc., now use text serif font rather than math upright.

Comment: Is it definitive? What if one wants upright math instead of text serif font?

Comment: It is indeed fixed.  Thank you!  Although I do have the same question as @Manuel’s.